# Passing dynamic array to function in c

Tags: c, function

After i create this dynamic arrays:

```
int *A = (int *) calloc(n,sizeof(int));
int *B = (int *) calloc(n,sizeof(int));
int *C = (int *) calloc(n,sizeof(int));
```

i need to pass them to this function `function2(A,B,C,n);` but i am getting implicit declaration of function 'function2'.Help please.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you declare function2() ?

Comment: I retagged this since it doesn't seem to have anything to do with dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 4):

You need to either declare or define the function before calling it. So something like:

```
void function2(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n)
{
    ...
}

int main(int, char **)
{
    int *A, *B, *C, n = 123;

    ...

    A = (int *) calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    B = (int *) calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    C = (int *) calloc(n,sizeof(int));

    function2(A, B, C, n);

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Or

```
void function2(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n);

int main(int, char **)
{
    int *A, *B, *C, n = 123;

    ...

    A = (int *) calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    B = (int *) calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    C = (int *) calloc(n,sizeof(int));

    function2(A, B, C, n);

    ...

    return 0;
}

void function2(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n)
{
    ...
}
```